# Any tricks for extracting 3d models, textures etc.. from a game?

Tags: reverse-engineering, extract

I have the client side program of a MMORPG.
The game sever have been stop running for about 7 years.
The game engine is proprietary so there should be no tools for resource extraction.

I have some basic programming skills. But not very knowledgeable about game programming. No experience on reverse engineering.

Any tips?

Comment: Well, you debug executable, find the code that reads resources, figure out how it processes it and that's it. Hard, cumbersome, but possible.

Comment: Hi is possible with python tool script running around ebx files and chunk to extract files (audio, texture, images, .obj, 3ds...) but you need to known python and reversing resources  here is an example on Bf's games http://www.bfeditor.org/forums/index.php?/topic/15731-file-dumper-for-sbtoc-archives/ you can start with this code to adapt on your context, regards. But i guess isn't a place to talk about this so if you want to jump to a site on high level to this question i suggest to go to unkowncheats.me site where you can find very nice helpful about those question.

Comment: @Arrowd, I tried that before. But i was focusing on the network part and felt so hopeless because of all those unreadable decompiled code. Maybe try looking for file reading would be different. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @headmax, I know a little bit python so I'll definitely read more anout that. Thanks for the suggestion. I always don't know where to start off

Comment: @Tsz Fung Li in reverse engineering most dump from binary isn't the same depend or more specific thing like (language code source used, processor used, packacking,  ...).